# Trouble understanding Standard deviation

Tags: calculus, statistics, standard-deviation

What is the official proof for the standard deviation?
And why we use n-1 when taking a sample rather than n? And how will n-1 will be affective if we took a sample of 1million  from 90million popularion?

Comment: There's no _proof_ for standard deviation since it's not a theorem. There is only _definition_ of standard deviation. As for $n-1$, that's because we want an unbiased estimator.

Comment: By the way, it has nothing to do with calculus of variations.

Comment: While it's not correct to talk about 'proof' for a definition, challenging the use of $n-1$ in the denominator of the sample variance is very perceptive on your part. (+1 to cancel someone's -1) See Answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Misakov is correct that $n-1$ is part of the definition of the sample standard deviation. So there is no 'proof' that one should use $n-1$ instead of $n$.
However, there are *reasons* that $n-1$ appears in the definition.

The reason can be explained at various levels. I'll give a few.

**Computational.**

The sample variance is defined as $S^2 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n-1}$ and the standard deviation (SD) is the square root of that.
Suppose you want to compute the variance of data 3, 1, 6, 2 with $n = 4.$ First, the sample mean is 
$\bar X = (3 + 1 + 6 + 2)/4 = 3.$ Then you might
use the following table:

```
 Index    Observation   Deviation from Mean  Squared Deviation
 -------------------------------------------------------------
   1           3            3 - 3 =  0              0
   2           1            1 - 3 = -2              4
   3           6            6 - 3 =  3              9
   4           2            2 - 3 = -1              1
 -------------------------------------------------------------
 Total        12                0                  14
```

So $S^2 = 14/3$ and the SD $S = \sqrt{14/3} = 2.16.$

Now imagine that the second row is, for some reason, illegible (faulty
FAX transmission or old photocopy machine). Then, given the the rest of
the table including the totals, you could reconstruct the data and
the variance. (E.g., 3 + smudge + 6 + 2 = 12, so smudge must be 1.
And similarly, $(X_2 - \bar X)^2$ must be 4.)

To describe this situation the terminology 'degrees of freedom' (df) has been
used. *Given the structure of the computation,* only three of the observations
carry information, not four. So we say df $ = n - 1 = 4 - 1 = 3.$
That is why we 'average' the squared deviations by dividing by df instead of $n.$

**Linear Algebra.**

Statisticians tend to think of data $X = (3, 1, 6, 2)$ as a vector in $n$-dimensional space. Roughly speaking, one linear relationship is used to estimate the population mean $\mu$ by $\bar X$, leaving $n-1$ dimensions to estimate the
population variance $\sigma^2$ by $S^2.$ In many applications 'degrees of
freedom' means sub-dimensions in an n-dimensional space.

**Estimation.**

If $S^2$ is defined with $n-1$ in the denominator, then considering $S^2$
as a random variable, we have $E(S^2) = \sigma^2.$ Roughly, this means that
when the sample variance is used to estimate the population variance it is
an 'unbiased' estimator--not always giving the exact value of $\sigma^2$
but not systematically either overestimating or underestimating $\sigma^2.$
If we were to define the sample variance as $V = \frac{\sum (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n},$ then, as an estimate of $\sigma^2,$ the estimate $V$ would tend to be
too small.

*Notes:* (1) if $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N$ is considered as the entire population,
then we define $\sigma_X^2 =  \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N (X_i - \bar X)^2}{N}.$
If you have a statistical calculator, you may have two buttons for the
variance, one labeled (for abbreviation) something like $\sigma_{n-1}$
and another labeled  $\sigma_{N}$;  the former is for the *sample* variance
and the latter for the *population* variance.

(2) You are certainly not the first person to wonder about this. A few elementary statistics texts (e.g, Freedman, Pisani, and Purves) have defined $S^2$ with $n$ in the
denominator, on the grounds that for large $n$ there is not much difference
between using $n$ and $n-1.$ That has not become standard, possibly because it requires
extra discussion later on when doing estimation from small samples and when using
Student's t and chi-squared distributions for hypothesis testing or making confidence intervals. Also, I have seen a few recent statistics-education oriented articles that advocate using $n.$

(3) [Added later] I see you asked about using $n-2$ or $n-3$. Those aren't good choices. But when using *normal data,* there is some theoretical justification for $n$ or $n+1.$ Dividing by these gives biased results, but unbiasedness isn't everything. Criteria for the estimate being 'close' to $\sigma^2$ indicate $n$ or $n+1$ might be desirable ('minimum mean absolute error' and 'minimum mean squared error', respectively).

Comment: Why n-2 and n-3 are not good choices?

Comment: Not only biased but also, on average, give estimates far from $\sigma^2.$ If you would say something about the level of your course, it would be easier to give answers at the right mathematical level. But both Answers to date give useful info, some of which should help.

Comment: If I showed you simulation results for mean squared errors of various denominators (for $n - 1$ thru $n + 1$ would that be helpful?

Comment: Ya it will be so helpful

Comment: Hope to do that later today. Breakfast with coffee and grading some papers are top priorities for next few hrs.

Comment: Take your time sir. Thank you for your effort to let me understand the topic

Answer (score 0):

First, when people say "standard deviation", they could mean a tons of different things: population standard deviation, sample standard deviation, corrected sample standard deviations, standard deviation of a random variable, etc.

It is well-known that given a random variable $X$, its standard deviation is simply the square root of its variation. That is,

$$\sigma(X)=\sqrt{\text{Var}[X]}$$

The "standard deviation" that has $n-1$ term is most likely to be the "corrected sample standard deviation". The reason we have $n-1$ instead of $n$ is that, if you use $n$, your estimation of the population standard deviation will be biased.

Comment: Why not n-2 or n-3

Comment: @OmarAli Oh, because only $n-1$ gives you unbiased estimate.

Comment: @OmarAli But of course, if you don't care about unbiasedness, then you don't have to use $n-1$.

Comment: Could you please calrify what does unbiased estimate mean?

Comment: @OmarAli https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction

Comment: @OmarAli: Lindgren's math stat book uses $n + 1$ for normal data based on minimum mean squared error $E(T - \sigma^2)^2$, where $T = \frac{\sum (X_i - \bar X)^2}{n+1}.$ See note (3) added to my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Extended comment:** This is an additional posting to give simulated results for mean squared error (MSE) and mean absolute error (MAE), using various denominators $n-1, n-2, \dots, n+2$ in estimating the population variance. This simulation arose out of a discussion with OP that extends a bit beyond the original Question. Results here are for *normal* samples of size $n=5,$
specifically $Norm(\mu = 100, \sigma = 15).$ But the general conclusions hold for other normal populations and other $n$ as well. Distinctions between
denominators are relatively large for $n = 5.$

The MSE of is a criterion for 'closeness' of an estimator $T$ to a parameter $\tau.$
$$ MSE_T = E[(T - \tau)^2] = b_T^2 + Var(T),$$
where the 'bias' $b_T = E(T - \tau).$ Thus the MSE of  an unbiased estimator is equal to its variance. In simulations it is usual to use $RMSE = \sqrt{MSE}$ in order to keep all quantities in the same units as the original population and data.

According to MSE, it is possible for an estimator with small bias and small variance to be judged 'better' than an unbiased estimator with large variance.

Another criterion for closeness is $MAE_T = E[|T - \tau|],$ which puts less
emphasis on extreme estimation errors.

Letting $Q = \sum(X_i - \bar X)^2,$ the simulation below with normal data shows results for 
estimators $Q/(n-3)$ through $Q/(n+2).$ In addition to the usual $V_{std} = Q/(n-1),$ which is unbiased, "winners" are $V_y = Q/(n+1)$ (smallest MSE) and
$V_x = Q/n$ (smallest MAE). Based on a million normal samples of size $n = 5,$
values should be accurate to about three significant digits.

```
 SUMMARY TABLE WITH APRX VALUES
 Denom     Expectation   RMSE   MAE
 n-3       450           390    272
 n-2       300           226    160
 n-1       225*          160    122
 n         180           135    112*
 n+1       150           130*   113
 n+2       129           132    118
```

The simulation in R statistical software is shown below:

```
 m = 10^6; n = 5; x = rnorm(m*n, 100, 15);  DTA = matrix(x, nrow=m)
 a = rowMeans(DTA);  ssq = rowSums((DTA - a)^2)
 v.u = ssq/(n-3);  v.v = ssq/(n-2);  v.std = ssq/(n-1)
 v.x = ssq/n;  v.y = ssq/(n+1);  v.z = ssq/(n+2)
 mean(v.u); mean(v.v); mean(v.std); mean(v.x); mean(v.y); mean(v.z)
 [1] 450.0821
 [1] 300.0547
 [1] 225.041   # UNBIASED: pop var is 225
 [1] 180.0328
 [1] 150.0274
 [1] 128.5949
 # RMSEs
 sqrt(mean((v.u-225)^2)); sqrt(mean((v.v-225)^2)); sqrt(mean((v.std-225)^2))
 [1] 390.4485
 [1] 225.549
 [1] 159.5212  # exact: sqrt(2*15^4/(5-1) = 159.099
 sqrt(mean((v.x-225)^2)); sqrt(mean((v.y-225)^2)); sqrt(mean((v.z-225)^2))
 [1] 135.3076
 [1] 130.118   # smallest
 [1] 132.677

 # MAEs
 mean(abs(v.u-225)); mean(abs(v.v-225)); mean(abs(v.std-225))
 [1] 271.8954
 [1] 159.5899
 [1] 122.0998
 mean(abs(v.x-225)); mean(abs(v.y-225)); mean(abs(v.z-225))
 [1] 111.7595   # smallest
 [1] 112.5548
 [1] 117.9307
```

A plot of the simulated distributions of the six estimators is shown below.
Reading across the first row denominators $n-3$ and $n-2$ are objectionable
because of large positive bias with long tails of extreme overestimates. At lower right, $n + 2$ is objectionable because of large negative bias (not offset by the smaller right tail of extreme
overestimates). Vertical lines at $\sigma^2 = 225$ show the parameter value
being estimated.

[image]